# zeppelin 0.10.1 cannot connect the hive by use intercepter

Tags: apache-zeppelin

```
Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri:
 jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000?tez.application.tags=paragraph_1706777624676_1735934812;mapreduce.job.tags=paragraph_1706777624676_1735934812;:
 Failed to open new session: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot modify tez.application.tags at runtime. It is not in list of params that are allowed to be modified at runtime
```

[image]

and

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVGvS.png)]

can you help me resove the problem

Comment: Hello and welcome! Is it an Apache Zeppelin problem or an Hive one?